# Firebird 2.5 database stuck in delta

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

We have a large firebird SQL Database stuck in delta.

nbackup -F reports database not in backup state.

nbackup -N reports delta file error.

No connections are possible as the database is in backup mode and the delta file is damaged.

Does anyone know of a way to edit the FDB (or use a tool) to force out of backup mode?

Comment: Have you tried executing `ALTER DATABASE END BACKUP`? Also edit your question and include the full error message you get with `nbackup -N`. Consider asking this question on the Firebird-support mailing list, you're more likely to get an answer there.

Comment: As we can't connect there is no way to run ALTER DATABASE END BACKUP even psql moans on connect. 

I have posted in a few places and will update the error shortly

Comment: `psql`? That is not a Firebird command-line tool. In any case, this sounds like a database corruption issue, and I think you'll get more help on the Firebird-support mailing list, as the core Firebird developers are also subscribed to that list.

Comment: i'd shutdown firebird services, made the database file(s) copy, and then tried two things after restarting the server: used gstat(or gfix? gsec? don't recall ATM) to turn DB into some shutdown mode and back, used last version of FB 2.5.x embedded to connect and pump data out of the DB. Also, gfix for full validation. But - AFTER making backup copies with stopped FB services.

Comment: Also, add more details (like exact FB version and edition, existence of the already established and lingering connections, database file headers report by gstat) and ask it on firebird-support mailing list.

Comment: What is the EXACT VERBATIM error text ? are you trying to unlock the original database or to unlock its nbak-made copy? https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/user_manuals/html/nbackup-lock-unlock.html